# How to use shared ItemGroup element in batching tasks

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks, msbuild-4.0

I'm trying to automate the creation of Firefox addon for two different platforms by using MSbuild:
I have shared files set which are the same for Mac and Windows and have platform specific files.

I want to batch the task of making XPI(which is just a renamed Zip file) by platform, but I can't find the right way to add the platform agnostic(shared) files as input for Zip task. Currently, my solution is to duplicate shared files items with platform windows and with platform mac, and then batch Zip task by Platform parameter. I have a feeling that my solution is not optimal. Maybe community can propose a better solution. Below is the simplified solution I created with comments:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectMSBuildToolsPath Condition=" '$(ProjectMSBuildToolsPath)' == '' ">MSBuild</ProjectMSBuildToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Required Import to use MSBuild Community Tasks -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <!-- Default platform type is shared-->
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ZipFiles>
      <Platform>Shared</Platform>
    </ZipFiles>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ZipFiles Include="chrome\overlay.js" />     

    <ZipFiles Include="chrome\Win\methodContainer.js">
      <Platform>Win</Platform>
    </ZipFiles>

    <ZipFiles Include="chrome\Mac\dataContainer.js">
      <Platform>Mac</Platform>
    </ZipFiles>       

  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="_PrepareItemsForZip" Outputs="$(Platform)">           
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Merge Shared and Windows specific files -->
      <ZipFilesToWin Include="@(ZipFiles)" Condition="('%(ZipFiles.Platform)' == 'Shared') Or ('%(ZipFiles.Platform)' == 'Win')" >
        <Platform>Win</Platform>
      </ZipFilesToWin>     
      <!-- Merge Shared and Mac specific files -->
      <ZipFilesToMac Include="@(ZipFiles)" Condition="('%(ZipFiles.Platform)' == 'Shared') Or ('%(ZipFiles.Platform)' == 'Mac')" >
        <Platform>Mac</Platform>
      </ZipFilesToMac>
    </ItemGroup>
        <!-- Merge Mac and Windows files set -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <_ZipFiles Include="@(ZipFilesToWin);@(ZipFilesToMac)" />
    </ItemGroup> 

  </Target>
  <!-- batch zipping files based on input platform -->
  <Target Name="MakeXPI" DependsOnTargets="_PrepareItemsForZip"  Inputs="@(_ZipFiles)" Outputs="%(Platform)" >
    <Message Text="Zipped files: @(_ZipFiles) %(Platform)"   Importance="high"/>
    <Zip Files="@(_ZipFiles)" WorkingDirectory="" ZipFileName="CoolAddon-%(Platform).xpi" ZipLevel="9" />    
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: have you tried solution I've proposed?

Comment: I don't understand how to use your solution?

Comment: ok, as far as I understand you are duplicating property `Platform` across multiple MSBuild scripts, I proposed to extract shared properties in a separate file `SharedProperties.properties` and then just import it

Comment: Oh, sorry. My explanation of the problem wasn't clear enputh. The problem what I have not with duplicating Platform property. I want to make a batch task only on Mac and Win platform which will take Shared also. But by default batch will take into account Shared, so I will run task three times, for Mac, Win and Shared. So my solution is to change Shared to Mac and Win twice before build. In this case batching will run twice.

Comment: sorry but still not sure whether got it right, so you want to run Zip task 1) one time 2) for all three platforms Mac/Win/Shared? If so why not simply do the same for Shared as you doing for ZipFilesToWin and ZipFilesToShared?

Comment: No I want run Zip task twice. But I have files in shared section which same on two platforms. So I'm looking for way to run Zip task optimal without need of duplication Shared items.

Comment: No I didn't. I should build solution for Mac and Windows only, but I have items which are the same in windows and mac, I mark them shared. Extracting properties doesn't help, because I'm looking for a way to use batch build which treat shared as windows or as mac depends on which configuration selected. Currently I'm doung this with intermediate target which substitute clone all shared into Mac and Windows list, so I'm looking for the more optimal solution if such exists.

Answer (score 0):

Extract them to file like `SharedProperties.properties`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
   <ZipFiles>       
      <Platform>Shared</Platform>     
   </ZipFiles>   
<PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And then simply import in targets/script you need them:

```
<Project ... >
     <Import Project="SharedProperties.properties" />
```